# GLTF/GLB Export in ThreeJS: Disrupting Scene Hierarchy

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I am exporting my scene using a very basic approach:

```js
function save(blob, filename) {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = filename;
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link);
}

function saveString(text, filename) {
  save(new Blob([text], { type: "text/plain" }), filename);
}

function saveArrayBuffer(buffer, filename) {
  save(new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), filename);
}

const exporter = new GLTFExporter();
exporter.parse(
  scene,
  function (result) {
    const name = `${modelName}.glb`;
    if (result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      saveArrayBuffer(result, name);
    } else {
      const output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
      saveString(output, name);
    }
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  },
  {
    binary: true,
    animations: [mixer.clipAction(model.animations[0]).getClip()],
  }
);
```

But as can be understood from the title, the hierarchy in my scene is being disrupted. Typically, my objects are directly placed under the scene. However, during the export process, a new empty object is created, and all my objects are nested within it. I desire to maintain the original structure of my scene.

**before**

[image: before]

**after**

[image: after]

*note: my scene contains animations that belong to objects.*

Comment: Do you mean that the scene *currently in browser memory* is modified during the export process? Or that when you export the scene and then import it back into three.js afterward, the resulting scene is different than the original?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I have a GLB file that I am importing into the scene using `GLTFLoader`. I want to make some modifications to it, such as renaming it. However, even if I don't make any changes and export it, then import it back into three.js, the scene remains visually the same. The issue is that my objects (meshes) end up being placed under a new object (Object3D) instead of being directly part of the scene.

Comment: For the purposes of Stack Overflow, I'm afraid the answer is basically, "yes this is what three.js does", i'll post an answer to that effect, but I do see your [question in the forums](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-glb-export-in-threejs-disrupting-scene-hierarchy/53035), perhaps a longer discussion there can lead to some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because glTF is not a three.js-specific format, its structures (nodes, meshes, primitives, ...) are not 1:1 analogs of three.js structures (Scene, Group, Object3D, Mesh, ...). three.js does the conversion in one direction during loading, and in another direction during export, with the goal of preserving the visual correctness of the scene.

Unfortunately, as you've found here, there's no guarantee that the round-trip will reproduce the exact underlying structure of the original three.js scene. There are some other related implications – texture are recompressed, and might lose a little quality.

There might be other ways to go about this, depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, but that might be better suited for a forum discussion than a Stack Overflow Q/A.